# Center 4 images with constraints autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, autolayout

I'm new to autolayout and i'm kind of stuck on how to center these 4 images in all different devices like it looks on the images. i've tried to apply the auto configured constraints but then it will have that distance and that does not fit on all devices. So my question is what constraints do i need to apply on all different images in order to make all image centered with same distance?

Here is how my cell in storyBoard looks like:

[image]

image of the constraint options on image 1:

[image]

image in simulator:

[image]

/// MY TRY ////

Here you can see the constraints that i've added and the result?

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: One advice is just create a container view for your image views. Then center that container view in your view controller's view.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your approach is almost correct, it simply lacks size constraints for the images.

If you want to dynamically resize the images and keep the space between them constant, put constraints on the images for the width to be `>=20`(or any other value, depends on your needs) and a constraint for keeping the aspect ratio. Then ctrl-drag from `UIImageView1` to `UIImageView2` and set a constraint for *equal widths*. Repeat that from `UIImageView1` to `UIImageView3` and from `UIImageView1` to `UIImageView4`.

[image]

---

If you want the images to always keep their fixed size and dynamically sized spaces between them you need another approach:

The trick here is to place 3 empty UIViews between the UIImageViews so that it looks like this:

[image]

- Set constraints to the top for all views
- Set constraints to the left and right for UIImageView1 and 4
- Set constraints for all UIImageViews to the same width
- Set constraints for all UIViews between the UIImageViews to the same width
- Set constraints for all the distances between the views to 0
- Set the width constraints for the UIViews to `>= 0`

This way makes the empty UIViews between the UIImageViews to resize dynamically and all the same width.

I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Hey thank you for your time. i can see u already made a demo project. For the showing purpose. i've been struggling and it still does not seem to have the result. could u share the project with me. thank you in advance

Comment: I have edited my answer, please check if that solves your problem.

Comment: If i choose the first approach i guess i need to make the cell Height dynamical. How could this look like?

Comment: This trick really solved my problem. That's unbelievable that autolayout sometimes is quite hard (or at least not trivial) for basic problems.

Answer (score 0):

For the first image add a leading space to superview and for the last image add a trailing space to superview and add vertical spacing between first and second, second and third, third and fourth and also set horizontally center within the container to each of the images

Comment: i've tried doing exactly what u said. look in my question at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

The objects on your storyboard require **at least 4 constraints per object**.

When there's orange lines around the UIImageView object like appears in your question, this means a constraint is missing, or conflicting and can often mean the image does not display at runtime like you'd expect.

In the first instance I recommend you select all objects and 'clear constraints', then start again.

Although not exactly the same, here is a link to an answer which explains the auto-layout constraints in a bit more detail. Once you understand it, auto-layout can be very powerful.

[>>Link to similar auto-layout issue - iOS CustomTableViewCell: elements not aligning correctly<<](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25775111/2507277)

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you want the images to always keep their fixed size and dynamically sized spaces between them then very easiest way first you drag the four UIView in your StoryBoard 
set constrain top left right and height for all the UIViews and give the equally width to all the UIViews(drag from one UIView to another and sets its equally width repeat this work for all the UIViews).

[Image about layouts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrWRN.png)

Secondly you have to drag your images set in these UIViews and sets their constrain height width and centre horizontal in container and centre vertically in container.

In last set the background colour of all UIViews default(white) you get the result it will work....i assure.

[Screenshot of Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGzde.png)