# Xcode 6 interface builder - horizontally align labels

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder, xcode6

How can I align 4 UILabels horizontally with equal spacing between them using Xcode 6 interface builder. I would like the labels to be a little bit off the top of the view and central. Each label will also has another related label underneath it which needs to align up like the image below.

[image]

Is there any other component that is easier to use for aligning in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Give these constraints for the labels :

Label1 (10)   : Top space to container  ,
                Leading space to container
Label2 (10)   : Top space to container ,
                Horizontal spacing  - to Label1(10)
Label3 (DAYS) : Leading space to container , 
                Verical spacing  - to Label1(10)
Label4 (HOURS) : Horizontal spacing  - to Label3(DAYS) , 
                Verical spacing  - to Label2(10)

Comment: In the interface builder this looks perfect however when loading it on a simulator some of the labels disappear off to the right of the screen :(

Comment: any idea how to make this work so all label fit within the screen width?

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to place the two labels in a separate UIView which deals as a container. Set the size of the view accordingly. Then you can drop the 2 labels on this UIView and set their constraints that the labels are centered horizontally within its superview. Do the same for the second box.

Looks like this. I colored the underlying UIView to gray so that it is visible here.

[image]

The constraints are:

1. Width and height of the UIView to 100
2. Label1 (10): Margin top top and center horizontally in container
3. Label2 (Days): Vertical distance to Label1 and center horizontally in container

The view itself can be positioned to your needs.

My answer on this question can possible give more thoughts: [Center 4 images with constraints autolayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431872/center-4-images-with-constraints-autolayout/26432911#26432911)

Comment: How can I get this to be evenly spaced horizontal with the other boxes (hours, minutes, seconds) on any screen size?

Comment: Please see the 2nd part of the answer I have linked. You should get the idea there.

Answer (score 0):

I wish Xcode made this easier. My solution is to add an invisible view that is centered and locked to the top layout guide, and then base everything else off that.

To start, drag a UIView onto your view controller, and change the background color to something other than white. Give it these constraints:

- top space to top layout guide (of main view)
- center horizontally in container (of main view)
- height 10
- width 100

Now that that's locked in, create constraints from your label to that view - vertical space, horizontal space, center X, whatever you like. Finally, change the reference view to be transparent and you're all set.