# Center 4 Images and maintain aspect ratio

Tags: ios, autolayout, center

[image: Center 4 Images]

I cannot figure out how to get these images to centre.  I like how I got them resizing accordingly for each device but would like to have them sit in the centre.  I feel like I'm missing something super obvious but after a week of daily 1-2 hour sessions of trying... I give up.

If the link (Centre 4 Images) to my screenshot works, you can see they are fitting to each device just fine, only not centred.

** The images left to right are 1, 2, 3, 4.

Comment: What's your deployment target? iOS 9, or earlier?

Comment: Earlier as well as iOS9 if that's possible.  I found a suggestion of using StackView but it requires iOS9 right?

Comment: `UIStackView` is the easiest solution but yes it requires iOS 9.

Answer (score 0):

Put the imageviews (1,2,3,4) inside a UIView (say ContentView) and give it two constraints - Top space to container, and Center horizontally in container.
I'm assuming that you're imageViews are set up in such a way (having height, and bottom and top space to container constraints) that they would provide the height of ContentView.

That would help you center ContentView containing all the four images.

Hope that helps. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Do you mean ContainerView?  Or UIView?

Comment: Just a normal UIView would do.

Comment: I can't figure it out so I'll try again later.  One question though, will all my animations, fade ins on start up, gestures and image changes from UIButtons work if I use this UIView as a container for my images?

Comment: Yes of course. I can't see why they would work any differently except that now the UIView would be the parent/superview of the UIImages.

Comment: I'm trying to follow this post but I can't get the darn images to enter.    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431872/center-4-images-with-constraints-autolayout