# Warning for autolayout when view controller loads

Tags: ios, ios8, autolayout, xcode6

Have tried my best to read some other posts but still stumped on why this is throwing a warning for my autolayout, and was hoping someone could offer a suggestion. I'm in xcode6.

Question # 1 - is it generally OK to have these warnings/crashes for autolayout constraints? Or is this a really serious thing that I should try my utmost to resolve?

Question # 2 - here is the output. I feel like it's related to when I set the aspect ratio on the items in my view controller (I have 3 views as rectangles, and I want them to be 15%, 60%, 25% of the height and full equal widths). I thought telling it to preserve aspect ratios is the right way to handle this?

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8a66031bc0 V:[UITableView:0x7f8a65837c00(73)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8a6605c150 UITableView:0x7f8a65837c00.width == 7.78082*UITableView:0x7f8a65837c00.height>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8a6604e970 UICollectionView:0x7f8a65838400.leading == UIView:0x7f8a66031eb0.leadingMargin>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8a6604e9c0 UICollectionView:0x7f8a65838400.trailing == UIView:0x7f8a66031eb0.trailingMargin>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8a6604ea10 UICollectionView:0x7f8a65838400.width == UITableView:0x7f8a65837c00.width>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8a63c4ccf0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UIView:0x7f8a66031eb0(320)]>"
)
```

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: The warnings should be OK to run and test, though like @hodson suggests it's putting off the inevitable, eventually you'll want to sort them. I recommend selecting all objects on your storyboard and clearing the constraints then adding them all again one by one, where each object requires at least 4 constraints. Here's a link to an answer that will help you through this process of adding the constraints. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25775111/2507277

Comment: Thanks I ended up giving some clarity to what it is I want to achieve, but thought it deviated from the original post and so made a new post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27174222/achieving-this-layout-for-a-viewcontroller-using-autolayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@(NO) forKey:@"_UIConstraintBasedLayoutLogUnsatisfiable"];
```

This console warnings doesn't make any issues. 
Add this code inside appdelegate. This will hide constraint error messages from console

Comment: Nice solution, that's exactly what I need.
I calculate height of collection view by using  *systemLayoutSizeFitting* method. But it always outputs auto-layout warnings. Which is ok in such cases but I don't want my console being polluted.

Answer (score 0):

1) I would recommend you fix the issue rather than leave it in there. You are probably okay to leave them there if you've tested the app and it looks like you want but you're just putting off the inevitable.

2) Seeing your constraint code would make it easier to see where you're going wrong. What you want to be doing though is set the multiplier to the following values:

- Rectangle 1: 15.0f/100.0f
- Rectangle 2: 60.0f/100.0f
- Rectangle 3: 25.0f/100.0f

Comment: thanks for your help - when you say code, what do you mean? i'm not doing anything in code but rather just on storyboard. Is there a way to export those into code? thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise you was using the storyboard. I type all my views out in objective-c code. If you really want to convert your storyboards to code you may be able to use [nib2objc](https://github.com/akosma/nib2objc) but you should be able to solve your issue in the storyboard itself, but I can't really help with that as I don't use them.

Comment: I actually posted with more clarity here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27174222/achieving-this-layout-for-a-viewcontroller-using-autolayout