# Unable to satisfy constraints in collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Essentially, I want to collect data within the cells of a collection view. The cells can have a fixed or small range of widths, constant height, and contain the same basic UI elements. As more cells are created, they should 'flow' across and down the screen.

I'm trying (first time) to set up a UICollection view that should load one cell, which has a text field and some buttons with constraints in IB, and a footer supplementary view with a button to add cells. The view loads with the initial cell in the simulator (no footer), but I get errors in my log at run time. There are no constraint errors prior to run-time, and I've tried many variations. In the log, the constraint that stands out is: NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fbc3ae4fdc0 h=--& v=--& V:[UIView:0x7fbc3ac3a270(50)]. I've not added any UIViews, nor can I see any in the Storyboard menu of scenes, controllers and views. If I set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false, I get an error: 'Must translate autoresizing mask into constraints to have _setHostsLayoutEngine:YES.'

What else is happening here, and how can I effectively control my layout here.

Comment: Have you added constraints to all objects within the UICollectionViewCell, so each have a minimum of 4 constraints to pin them down at runtime? If not, this could be the issue, please see this answer which details about how to go about setting up the cell correctly with constraints. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25775111/2507277 I hope this helps with your problem

Comment: I followed the pattern of adding top and left constraints plus the width and height, and as you suggest all constraints were OK at run time! My problem then was that I wanted neither fixed widths nor height, but adding any constraint to the trailing margin of the cell brought the errors back. Then I realized the width of the cell itself, when set in code, must be conflicting with the width of contents within the cell. Thank you Jim for opening the crack. If you think it worth your while, put an answer - see comments, and I'll mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered in comments. Basically, the size of the cell was smaller than its contents. I eventually made the cell's constraint greater than or equal to the size I wanted. All errors disappeared, but I do live in fear of a giant cell at run time.